# Should we use redux saga for post requests?

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga

Should we use the redax saga when we make a post request to the server but expect to receive some data after that and dispatch it to the store?

For example, I send a post request on page reload if the user is logged in to check if his token is valid, and if so, update the state in the store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redux Saga is primarily used for side-effects management. So to answer your question - yes.